# How to create a custom OL list?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an easy way for me to write tab for guitar and would like the notes to be visible on the left.
IE:

E

A

D

G

B

e

Chord

Is there a way to define a custom list? Something like below:

```
<div class="Tab">
<ol type="E, A, D, G, B, e, Chord">
    <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why use a list for this?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you want to accomplish. Perhaps this might work: `... placeholder="-">E</li>`?

Comment: Just use labels

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can achieve this using HTML & CSS alone because they have a predefined set of counters. Even counters you can't make a custom one. What you can do is, using CSS `::before` pseudo element and `:nth-child()` you can achieve what you want to do:

```css
.guitar li {
  list-style: none;
}
.guitar li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 1)::before {
  content: "E";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 2)::before {
  content: "A";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 3)::before {
  content: "D";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 4)::before {
  content: "G";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 5)::before {
  content: "B";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 6)::before {
  content: "e";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 7)::before {
  content: "Chord";
}
```

```html
<ol class="guitar">
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
</ol>
```

We have rewritten the way this whole thing works. So if you have another list like this, it will be something like this:

```css
.guitar li {
  list-style: none;
}
.guitar li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 1)::before {
  content: "E";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 2)::before {
  content: "A";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 3)::before {
  content: "D";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 4)::before {
  content: "G";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 5)::before {
  content: "B";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 6)::before {
  content: "e";
}
.guitar li:nth-child(8n + 7)::before {
  content: "Chord";
}
```

```html
<ol class="guitar">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use label elements

```css
.Tab ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.Tab label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="Tab">
  <ol>
    <li><label for="t-E">E</label><input type="text" id="t-E" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><label for="t-A">A</label><input type="text" id="t-A" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><label for="t-D">D</label><input type="text" id="t-D" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><label for="t-G">G</label><input type="text" id="t-G" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><label for="t-B">B</label><input type="text" id="t-B" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><label for="t-e">e</label><input type="text" id="t-e" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
    <li><label for="t-C">Chord</label><input type="text" id="t-C" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: This definitely doesn't answer the question and I am pretty sure you didn't understand what's needed.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman It says "I want the notes to show up on the left".... Well it does. I personally think you are reading into the question a lot more than what the OP provided.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that way.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I wasn't very clear

Answer (score 0):

CSS variables can help here:

```css
ol li::before {
  content: "- " var(--list) " " var(--list) " " var(--list) " " var(--list); /* as much as possible */
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  right: calc(100% + 5px);
  height:100%;
  line-height:21px; /* you need to make this equal to the height*/
  direction: rtl;
  transform:translateY(calc(var(--p)*-100%))
}
/* you can easily generate the below using SASS/LESS */
ol li:nth-child(1)::before {--p:1}
ol li:nth-child(2)::before {--p:2}
ol li:nth-child(3)::before {--p:3}
ol li:nth-child(4)::before {--p:4}
ol li:nth-child(5)::before {--p:5}
ol li:nth-child(6)::before {--p:6}
ol li:nth-child(7)::before {--p:7}
ol li:nth-child(8)::before {--p:8}
ol li:nth-child(9)::before {--p:9}
/* ol li:nth-child(N)::before { --p:N}*/

ol {
  overflow:hidden;
}
ol li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(-100vw 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, -100vw 100%); /* hide the overflow and show only one line */
}
```

```html
<ol style="--list:'E A D G B e Chord';">
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
</ol>

<ol style="--list:'1 3 OK C e hello';">
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tab line" placeholder="-"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Sweet. But should probably come with an accessibility warning.

Comment: @Alohci Why so?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - I tested it with the screen reader NVDA on Windows. Rather than reading out the visible portion, Firefox read out the whole list  for each row. Chrome read out none of the list, either way making the bullet value inaccessible to screen reader users.

Comment: Oh yes, that happens @Alohci.